# Problemas com resposta das rotas no laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

estou aprendendo o Laravel, e tem um exercício onde se passa duas rotas com o mesmo endereço no caso '/contato' porém com dois parametros diferente, um GET outro POST, e para cada parâmetro um return diferente como resposta, apenas para aprender rotas mesmo, porém, o meu codigo (laravel 5.8) só consegue responder ao método post, mesmo o que esta setado como GET, a resposta que entra é do post... Mesmo usando o Controller ainda sim, entra o POST

```
Route::get('/contato/{id?}' , ['uses'=>'ContatoController@index']);
Route::get('/contato',['uses'=>'ContatoController@criar'] );
Route::post('/contato',['uses'=>'ContatoController@editar'] );
```

Controller:

```
    public function index()
   {
      return "Esse é o Index do ContatoController";
    }
    public function criar()
   {
      return "Esse é o Criar do ContatoController";
    }
    public function editar()
   {
      return "Esse é o editar do ContatoController";
    }
```

Formulário:

```
<div>
                <h2>Teste com Rotas</h2>
                <form method="POST" action="/contato">
                @csrf
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome / POST">
                <button>Enviar</button>   
                </div>

                <div>
                <h2>Teste com Rotas</h2>
                <form method="GET" action="/contato">
                @csrf
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome / GET ">
                <button>Enviar</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Quando você dispara o form com method "GET", ele retorna a resposta da função POST "editar()" é isso que ta acontecendo ? no metodo GET creio que não precisa do @csrf apenas pro POST.

Comment: Exatamente isso